# jqGrid Search Box option pops up by default when grid is loaded

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using following jqgrid code :

```
        jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
        url:'<?php echo $url;?>',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames:[
            <?php 
                $sep = "";
                foreach($columns as $col){
                    echo $sep . "'" . $col['header'] . "'";                         
                    $sep = ","; 
                }
            ?>
        ],
        colModel:[              
            <?php 
                $sep = "";
                foreach($columns as $col){
                    echo $sep . "{name:'" . $col['name'] . "',index:'" . $col['name'] . "', width:" . $col['width'] . ", sortable:true, search:true}"; 
                    $sep = ","; 
                }
            ?>      
        ],
    rowNum:100,
    rowList:[100,200,300,400],
    pager: '#pager2',
        loadonce: true,
        sortname: 'geneID',
        viewrecords: true,
        width:700,
        shrinkToFit:false,
        height:700,
        sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"Breeder Tool Box"
    });


jQuery("#list2").navGrid('#pager2',{add: false, edit: false, del: false,search : true ,     refresh : true},{},{},{});
jQuery("#list2").searchGrid({multipleSearch:true});  // For Adding the Multiple Search Option on the jqgrid
```

Search box opens up by default , when ever the grid is loaded .

I am trying to get the search box only after click on the search option in lower part of jqgrid toolbar

Can you please point which part is missing / wrong in my code

Answer (score 2):

From the [wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching) in reference to the searchGrid method

```
Typically when this method is called it launches the modal dialog and makes it so the grid inaccessible until the dialog is closed.
This method is not the default search method in the navigator. To enable this you should either set the default search options using the extend method or set it in the navigator in the place of the search options.
```

So you were calling the search modal not assigning the grid to have a search modal. You should instead assign the multiple search this way:

```
jQuery("#list2").navGrid('#pager2',
{add: false, edit: false, del: false,search : true ,refresh : true},
{},
{},
{},
{multipleSearch:true});
```

So then this line should be removed:

```
jQuery("#list2").searchGrid({multipleSearch:true});
```